# Best Practise to put cakephp application logs file on shared host

Tags: cakephp, logging, shared-hosting, syslog

Where shall I put cakephp application logs on shared host, for example justhost. CakePHP by default using FileLog as the mechanism to record application logs, while it’s highly recommended to use syslog when put it on production. Shared host service doesn’t have syslog daemon so it doesn’t work out. Currently CakePHP put application logs under app/tmp/logs/.log, as times goes on, the files will get larger and I also think application logs need separate from source codes(of course tmp directory is not tracked by git). Another concern logs directories need apache permission to read and write.  Question is where should I put the application logs file? what’s the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `tmp` folder out of `app` and have it on same level (that's what done in [CakePHP 3.0](https://github.com/cakephp/app)). Also in your `webroot/index.php` define the `TMP` constant to specify the new location: `define('TMP', ROOT . DS . 'tmp' . DS);`